# Why does XElement fall over when parsing an xml file with an xmlns?

Tags: c#, parsing, linq-to-xml, xml-namespaces, xelement

So I'm trying to parse an xml file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Root>    
  <att1 name="bob" age="unspecified" xmlns="http://foo.co.uk/nan">    
  </att1>    
</Root>
```

Using the following code:

```
XElement xDoc= XElement.Load(filename);
var query = from c in xDoc.Descendants("att1").Attributes() select c;
foreach (XAttribute a in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}",a.Name,a.Value);
}
```

Nothing is written to the console unless I delete xmlns="http://foo.co.uk/nan" from the xml file, after which, I get a list of attribute names and values as one would expect, and as I need!

Edit: Formatting.

Comment: By the way, there's no point in writing `from c in whatever select c`.

Comment: So there isn't!  Thanks :)  I'd picked that up from a very useful introduction to LINQ to XML here: http://www.microsoft.com/uk/msdn/nuggets/nugget/204/Querying-XML-in-C-with-LINQ-to-XML.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the same namespace in your code:

```
XElement xDoc= XElement.Load(filename);
XNamespace ns = "http://foo.co.uk/nan";
var query = from c in xDoc.Descendants(ns + "att1").Attributes() select c;
foreach (XAttribute a in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}",a.Name,a.Value);
}
```

Attributes don't pick up the default (`xmlns=....`) namespace, so you don't need to qualify them. The namespace tag (`xmln:tags=....`)is purely local to the document or API use, the names are really namespace + local name always so you have to always specify the namespace.

Comment: This did the trick perfectly, thanks.  Since the namespace is likely to change between xml files, I guess you have to load the file as a string, then look for the namespace and declare it in the code?

Comment: @zotty No string parsing is needed if you query against the LocalName as shown in my answer.

Comment: @zotty: If namespaces vary your code will be more verbose, and it is really missing the point of namespaces (the name of a node is namespace+local name), but this is sometimes necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Your call to [Descendants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813.aspx) is querying for an element named "att1" in no namespace.

If you called `Descendants("{http://foo.co.uk/nan}att1")` you would select the namespaced element but not the non-namespaced element.

You could select elements named "att1" in any or no namespace like this:

```
var query = from c in xDoc.Descendants() where c.Name.LocalName == "att1" select c.Attributes;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the namespace in the `Descendants` call, like this:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://foo.co.uk/nan";
foreach (XAttribute a in xDoc.Descendants(ns + "att1"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}",a.Name,a.Value);
}
```